# JSON List Combine Two Json FIles Together Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm creating a project which has a changeable json information with different json files , the problem is when I click on the first radio button it works good but when I click the second one the list will be shown perfectly but it's being parsed from two files. this is my code:

```
    public void showFoodItems(String shit)
{

    movieList.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(
            "http://users.abdullahadhaim.com/users/WebServiceResturant.asmx/getFoodItems?categoryName="
                    + shit, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setPrice(((Number) obj.get("price"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setOrderNum(obj.getInt("categoryno"));
                            movie.setCategory(obj.getString("category"));

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

    /* @#@#@#@# JSON Items ListView END @#@#@#@# */

}
```

And this the radioButton onCLick's methods:

```
rd1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /// movieList.clear();
        //  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //  listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            showFoodItems("Starter");

        }
    });


    rd2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  movieList.clear();
        //  //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            showFoodItems("Desserts");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Wild guess at what you're asking: is the problem that when you hit the second radio button you see both lists? If so, it's cause you're not clearing movieList before you start adding the new items from your json request.